# Plotly: How to change time widgets position?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

is it possible to change the position of the widget of a time animated plot in plotly? By default it is in the bottom of the plot, but it is covering the labels in my case.

[image]

This the cookbook of plotly: https://plotly.com/python/animations/

Comment: Hi Matteo, please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and edit any of the four padding properties of the slider using any of the four letters `b, l, r, t` which set the padding along the bottom of the component, on the left side, on the right side and along the top of the component, respectively, in:

```
fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t']
```

**Plot 1:** `fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t'] = 10`

[image]

**Plot 2:** ``fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t'] = 200`

[image]

Now of course it would make sense to adjust the padding of the updatemnu too. And you can do that in a similer manner with:

```
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']['t']
```

**Plot 3:** Adjusted slider and updatemenu

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig=px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

padding_top = 200

fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t'] = padding_top
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']['t'] = padding_top

fig.show()
```